# Getting request.getRequestURL() or request.getHeader("Referer") from urlrewrite redirect

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, url-rewriting

Currently, I have a /doc folder that redirects (when accessed through the browser) to a .jsp file.  This was set inside the web.xml..

When I try to retrieve the requestedURL or Referer, it outputs the .jsp file location.
How is it possible to retrieve the correct referer (that being the file located under the /doc)?

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/FOLDER/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<urlrewrite>
...
<rule>
    <from>/FOLDER/(.*)</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/authenticate.jsp</to>       
</rule>
```

---

Inside the .jsp file when I access /FOLDER/file.txt in the browser it will redirect to the authenticate.jsp page and display (authenticate.jsp) when I call these:

```
out.write(request.getHeader("Referer"));
out.write(request.getRequestURL().toString());
out.write(request.getRequestURI().toString());
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: updated in the comment Rohit.